# Send Notifications from Multiple Private Channels in Laravel Broadcasts

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, pusher, laravel-echo

I configured `pusher`, `Laravel Broadcasting`, `Laravel Echo` to send notifications to my users. It is working fine for the single private channel.

I have Two Private Channels.

1. App.User{id}
2. YouthAdd.YouthAdd{id}

But Notifications are passed only through `App.User{id}` Channel

How can I send notifications from  other channel too ?

**My User Class**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The channels the user receives notification broadcasts on.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
    {
        return 'App.User.'.$this->id;
        return 'YouthAdd.YouthAdd.'.$this->id;
    }
}
```

**My Channels.php Route file**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('YouthAdd.YouthAdd.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

**My Front End**

```
<script>
  var userId = $('meta[name="userId"]').attr('content');
    Echo.private('App.User.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        toastr.warning(notification.title, notification.name, {closeButton: true, timeOut: 5000000});
    });


      Echo.private('YouthAdd.YouthAdd.' + userId)
      .notification((notification) => {
          console.log(notification.youth);
          toastr.error(notification.youth.name, notification.youth.nic, {closeButton: true, timeOut: 5000000});
      });

    </script>
```

Anyone can answer this ?

Comment: you cant do multiple returns from a single function. Why exactly do you want different channels? Why not just listen on User channel if you want the same event?

Comment: I do have multiple events. so i need to send differnt events.

Comment: then you will have to broadcast them manually. Check: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#using-example-application

Comment: Here I'm Trying to send broadcast notification with database notification. I use same Notification class to tho this using `toBroadcast` and `toDatabase` . Im trying to send notifications through` laravel notification class` instead of `laravel event class` .

Answer (score 1):

instead of :

```
public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
{
    return 'App.User.'.$this->id;
    return 'YouthAdd.YouthAdd.'.$this->id;
}
```

try this:

```
public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
{
     return [
        'App.User.'.$this->id,
        'YouthAdd.YouthAdd.'.$this->id
    ];
}
```

Comment: I tried it. Its getting error called : `"message": "Array to string conversion",`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        $channelNames = ['App.User.' . $this->id, 'YouthAdd.YouthAdd.'.$this->id];
        $channels = [];
        foreach ($channelNames as $channel) {
            $channels[] = new PrivateChannel($channel);
        }

        return $channels;
```

Comment: I am getting error called `Array to string conversion`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$channels = array();

        foreach ($this->athletes as $athlete) {
            array_push($channels, new PrivateChannel('athlete.' . $athlete->user->id));
        }

        array_push($channels, new PrivateChannel('user.' . $this->user->id));

return $channels;
```